# Braintree payment with nodejs not working

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, braintree

I have the following html:

```
<form id="payment-form" method="post" submit="/checkout">
     <input type="submit" value="Pay $10">
     <input type="hidden" name="payment_method_nonce" value="0fgg1679-75e2-43e0-bc1f-94faee177877">
     <iframe src="https://assets.braintreegateway.com/dropin/2.28.0/inline-frame.html#3a713953-3106-4fd5-8714-b0ada1723284" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" name="braintree-dropin-frame" width="100%" height="68" id="braintree-dropin-frame" style="transition: height 210ms cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1); border: 0px; z-index: 9999; height: 70px;"></iframe>
</form>
```

The html was originally only the `input type=submit` and the `payment-form` but my javascript has the following code that transforms the elements into what is seen above:

```
braintree.setup(BT_CLIENT_TOKEN, "dropin", {
  container: "payment-form"
});
```

The BT_CLIENT_TOKEN is successfully instantiated in the server side to the client side.
When I open the website I can login to sandbox and see the following:

[image]

When I click "pay", however, the form is not submitted through my `app.post("/checkout")` on the nodejs server side but instead through the default route `app.post("/")`. Also, the body of the request always comes empty `req.body: {}` (and shouldn't  as far as I know, should come with the nounce at least).

Does anyone have any idea on what is happening? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

I have a couple of suggestions. First, be sure to define an `action` attribute in your `<form>`.

```
<form id="payment-form" method="post" action="/checkout">
```

Second, the Braintree Drop-in [requires a container](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/drop-in/javascript/v2#container) element to be nested *within* a `<form>`. It is this container element that should be targeted within `braintree.setup()`.

**HTML**

```
<form id="payment-form" method="post" action="/checkout">
  <div id="dropin-container"></div>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
braintree.setup('BT_CLIENT_TOKEN', 'dropin', {
  container: 'dropin-container'
});
```

Regarding `req.body: {}`, it is difficult to dig deeper without a more comprehensive look at your code and I'd prefer to avoid guessing without that context. If the suggestions above do not resolve the issue, perhaps you can edit your question and provide more code snippets to help the community examine this more closely.

Comment: Helo Shea, you are right indeed it was action, I noticed that almost after posting this question! :)

However, I'm facing another problem. I changed the form id where braintree is injected and for some reason, after logging in to brain tree, no nonce is generated (while it used to in the example above). Any idea on this? Tyvm!

Comment: Hi Fane. Please feel free to contact Braintree Support for follow-up questions: https://support.braintreepayments.com/.